# How do I remap WASD to arrow keys?

Tags: macos, keybindings

OK so, I saw this answer on another thread about how to remap keys:

> Apple's Technical Note TN2450 describes how to remap keys. Running the
>   following command will remap Right Alt to be Right Control.
>
> ```
> hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":
>     [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000e6,
>       "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x7000000e4}]
> }'
> ```

So I wrote this:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":
    [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000052,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000001A}
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000051,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000016}
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000050,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000004}
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000004F,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000007}]
}'
```

But when I run it I get this error:

```
2020-02-17 11:47:40.303 hidutil[2619:57497] NSJSONSerialization Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 

"Badly formed array around character 127." 

UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed array around character 127.}

ERROR!!!! Unable to create property object for 
'{"UserKeyMapping":
    [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000052,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000001A}
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000051,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000016}
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000050,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000004}
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000004F,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000007}]
}'
```

What's the problem?

(I'm a total noob just trying to remap a key for a game (EU:4), I'm not an expert programmer or anything, so please be gentle and explain things in layman's terms for my noob ass to understand! xD)

Thanks, R69NiX

Comment: Try mapping them one at a time.  Also, I believe array elements are separated by semicolons (;)

Comment: Ahhh thanks. Remapping one at a time like the the answer on the other thread seems to work fine. Thanks Allan :)

Comment: Type it up as an answer and accept it.  I'll up vote so you can get the reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not a programmer and want a very simple way, then I recommend using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap keys.

> A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for OS X.

[This page](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html) will give you step by step guidelines. You can achieve your setup as per my following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Ohh that looks easy to use. I tried a program called FastFox and didn't have a clue how to use it lol think I'll try that. Thank you Udhy :)

Comment: @R69NiX: Indeed, it is very easy and convenient too.