# Remap Mac Keys - Terminal

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I'm a newcomer here (you can tell by my question).

To remap a key, do I just replace the two hexadecimal values for the key I wants to be changed and use the entire string in Terminal?

`0x63` for `0x53`, and does that replace the entire `"0x700000004"` and `"0x700000005"`, for example?

```
$ hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000004,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000005},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000005,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000004}]}'
)
```

Comment: Do you need it from Terminal only or other alternative option will work for you?

Comment: I didn't know there were other options beside using Terminal?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I highly suggest taking the [Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) so you can get the most out of the site.  This question has been asked/answered several times, so a [quick search](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=remap+keys) turns up numerous posts.  If there's a specific question about remapping that none of the existing answers address, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @Desert-Rat: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382336/341892 - Check this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remap WASD to arrow keys?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382334/how-do-i-remap-wasd-to-arrow-keys)